# Error: An Unknown twitter exception in android app. What might be the error and how to debug?

Tags: android, oauth

I got the tweety app from here: github.com/fmaker/Tweety

Implemented it. Registered my app. Got the customer key and put it in the code. And, still, when I enter UserName and Password it gives an error: An Unknown Twitter Exception.

What might be the error? Is it an OAuth error?

This is my manifest.xmlt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.handycodeworks.tweety"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/twitter_bird" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name=".Tweety"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />



            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name="Prefs"></activity>
<service android:name="UpdateService"></service>
<activity android:name="Timeline">
</activity>
<receiver android:name="BootReceiver"><intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>

</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<activity android:name="About"></activity>


</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />





<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Anything wrong in this?

Still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

please try by changing your access token key on your twitter developer account.

and also check Internet permission in your Manifest file.

this post may helps you
[Android: UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314137/android-unknownhostexception)