# Android does not parse JSON out put

Tags: android, json

```
 {
   "German":[
      "Hello",
      "guten Morgen",
      "gute Nacht"
   ],
   "English":[
      "Hello",
      "good morning",
      "good Night"
   ],
   "French":[
      "bonjour",
      "bonne nuit",
      "bonjour"
   ]
}
```

In Android ,I have to parse this above output. I am unable to do. can any one tell me ,does it wrong jSON output or it is correct ?

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: post some code you have written...

Comment: i have copy code from above example

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: or you want to say ,send me code which cause for json response

Comment: ur json string is valid json string

Comment: define "unable to do"

Comment: DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); HttpResponse httpResponse =httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
 
i am getting error on httpclient.excute(httpPost) –  
 
saqib_abbasi.0fees.net/Response.php 
 
this is my url,url="saqib_abbasi.0fees.net/Response.php";
 
please tell me where i am getting wrong

Comment: @saqib, why are you using httpPost when the request is clearly a get ? You don't send anything to the server, only requesting from it.

Comment: first i have to call specific url to get JSON response.Resultant Json,it looks like that above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its problem with your URL - saqib_abbasi.0fees.net/Response.php

**Try after removing the underscore from your host name.**

See the following links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206362/1329126

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid json. So you didn't do something right.
Make a JSONObject from the whole string, then you can get the arrays with getJSONArray("German") for example.

Comment: DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse =httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: @saqib show us some code, we said before your json response is valid, so your parser is not good. Edit your original question and insert the json parser part of your code. Also an exception would be helpful. Also are you 100% sure you get the response from the server ?

Comment: @saqib your question is Android doesn't parse your JSON output, but where have you mentioned that you are failed to get response, please understand other's time, ask question properly.

Comment: Thanks your Time,your answer really help me.But i have find ,it is due to saqib_abbasi.0fees.net/Response.php ,it is not proper URL,it is way ,it is causing in Json Parser.